# Oracle SQL subquery scalar as input to other subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

In the below query, I'm using Subquery1 and Subquery2 to get Account Number and Account Name. However the first Subquery and second joins same tables except an additional table account_nameinfo_t in Subquery 2 to get the account name. Is there a way I avoid selecting from other tables and just use the value of Subquery 1 i.e account# to get the account name in Subquery 2?

```
SELECT 
       (
        SELECT acct.account_no
         FROM group_t grp1, account_t acct
        WHERE     grp1.poid_id0 = grpbm.obj_id0
              AND acct.poid_id0 = grp1.ACCOUNT_OBJ_ID0
       )  PARENT_ACCOUNT, -- (#Subquery 1 to get the parent account)
       (
        SELECT ant.Firstname || ' ' || ant.LastName
         FROM group_t grp1, account_t acct,account_nameinfo_t ant
        WHERE     grp1.poid_id0 = grpbm.obj_id0
              AND acct.poid_id0 = grp1.ACCOUNT_OBJ_ID0
              AND ant.obj_id0 = acct.poid_id0
       ) "ACCOUNT NAME", -- (#Subquery 2 to get the parent account name which is in a different table)
       bgs.REC_ID2 RECORD_TYPE,
       bgs.current_bal VALUE
 FROM group_t grp,
      group_billing_members_t grpbm,
      BAL_GRP_SUB_BALS_T bgs
WHERE     poid_type = '/group/sharing/discounts'
      AND grpbm.OBJECT_ID0 = grp.ACCOUNT_OBJ_ID0
      AND bgs.obj_id0 = grp.BAL_GRP_OBJ_ID0
      AND bgs.rec_id2 NOT IN (1000203,
                              1030001,
                              1000303,
                              1000306)
ORDER BY PARENT_ACCOUNT;
```

Comment: Why are you using subqueries instead of just joining to those tables? (And why are you using old-style join syntax instead of ANSI joins? You haven't referred to `account_nameinfo_t` in your code, though presumably that's what the `ant` table alias is derived from.)

Comment: @AlexPoole yes firstly , i missed referring to the table here in the comment but not in my sqldeveloper, since I had to type in here instead of copying. Secondly , yes will try the join as you suggested.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have achieved it using ANSI joins. I have posted the tested result in the answer section below. THanks for your clue and please comment if you find something wrong or betterment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can simplify this using simple joins rather than subqueries, either in the select list or as inline views:

```
SELECT acct.account_no AS "PARENT ACCOUNT",
  ant.first_name||' '||ant.last_name AS "ACCOUNT NAME",
  bgs.rec_id2 AS record_type,
  bgs.current_bal
FROM group_t grp
JOIN group_billing_members_t grpbm ON grpbm.obj_id0 = grp.account_obj_id0
JOIN group_t grp1 ON grp1.poid_id0 = grpbm.obj_id0
JOIN bal_grp_sub_bals_t bgs ON bgs.obj_id0 = grp.bal_grp_obj_id0
JOIN account_t acct ON acct.poid_id0 = grp1.account_obj_id0
JOIN account_nameinfo_t ant ON ant.obj_id0 = acct.poid_id0
WHERE grp.poid_type='/group/sharing/discounts'
AND bgs.rec_id2 not in (1000203, 1030001, 1000303, 1000306)
AND ant.rec_id = 1
ORDER BY "PARENT ACCOUNT";
```

You only seem to be using `group_billing_members_t` between two references to `group_t`, and it isn't clear if they both point to the same record, or if that expands to multiple rows. The column names seem a bit inconsistent, which may be from your retyping the code rather than copying and pasting it. If it is the same record then you seem to be able to remove that table and the rejoin:

```
SELECT acct.account_no AS "PARENT ACCOUNT",
  ant.first_name||' '||ant.last_name AS "ACCOUNT NAME",
  bgs.rec_id2 AS record_type,
  bgs.current_bal
FROM group_t grp
JOIN bal_grp_sub_bals_t bgs ON bgs.obj_id0 = grp.bal_grp_obj_id0
JOIN account_t acct ON acct.poid_id0 = grp.account_obj_id0
JOIN account_nameinfo_t ant ON ant.obj_id0 = acct.poid_id0
WHERE grp.poid_type='/group/sharing/discounts'
AND bgs.rec_id2 not in (1000203, 1030001, 1000303, 1000306)
AND ant.rec_id = 1
ORDER BY "PARENT ACCOUNT";
```

Without table structures, relationships, sample data and expected results that's rather speculative though.

Comment: Alex I get what you are saying now. I tried that as you suggested there is a problem, account_t cannot be directly joined with group. The idea is to get child account data and then search for parent account# in group again , use the parent account# to get the first and last name. The expectation is : Get the group members from group_t which have the poid_type = Get all sub balances from BAL_GRP_SUB_BALS_T of type that are not in 100023 e.t.c  to get the sub balances i have to join balance group members.

Comment: Once i get all the members, i will use member account id to connect group again, since it also have parent acct# , and then get the first and last name

Comment: OK, the first version is still doing that. It joins `grp` to `grpbm ` and then from there to `grp1`, But I just tried to recreate from the columns etc. I could see in the question, and if there are errors there from retyping it then I'll have those too.

Comment: It worked, there one issue with acct.poid_id0 = grp.account_obj_id0 it should be acct.group_obj_id0 . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports a `WITH` clause which you may find useful: http://psoug.org/reference/with.html

Essentially, it allows you to create a temporary view within a query that can be accessed multiple times.  In your case, the result of your common join can be "factored out" and the result can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

As ALEXPOOL suggested here is what i tried with ANSI joins and it works. Any betterment is welcome.

```
SELECT C1."PARENT ACCOUNT",C1."ACCOUNT NAME", A1.RECORD_TYPE, A1.CURRENT_BAL
FROM 
    (SELECT  
      bgs.REC_ID2 RECORD_TYPE,
      bgs.current_bal,grpbm.OBJ_ID0
    FROM  group_t grp ,
          group_billing_members_t grpbm,
          BAL_GRP_SUB_BALS_T bgs
        WHERE
        poid_type='/group/sharing/discounts'   and
      grpbm.OBJECT_ID0 = grp.ACCOUNT_OBJ_ID0 and
      bgs.obj_id0 = grp.BAL_GRP_OBJ_ID0      and
      bgs.rec_id2 not in (                    1000203,
                        1030001,
                            1000303,
                            1000306) ) A1 JOIN

  ( SELECT grp1.ACCOUNT_OBJ_ID0,grp1.POID_ID0
     FROM group_t grp1
  )  B1 ON (B1.poid_id0 = A1.OBJ_ID0)
  JOIN 
  ( SELECT acct.account_no "PARENT ACCOUNT",
            ant.FIRST_NAME||' '||ant.LAST_NAME "ACCOUNT NAME",
            acct.poid_id0 
     FROM 
        account_t acct,
        account_nameinfo_t ant  
        WHERE acct.poid_id0 = ant.obj_id0 and 
              ant.rec_id=1) C1 ON (C1.poid_id0 = B1.ACCOUNT_OBJ_ID0)
  order by C1."PARENT ACCOUNT";
```

Comment: Mixing old and new joins is strange and might confuse the optimiser. But I meant to eliminate the subqueries completely, not join to them as inline views, really.